# Remove directory name from url in htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to remove directory name from URL e.g.

- Current URL: `http://localhost/demo/xyz/app/index.php`
- New URL: `http://localhost/demo/xyz/index`

I have added a `.htaccess` file in the applications folder and added below code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteRule    ^$ app/$1    [L]
  RewriteRule    ^(.*) app/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

But it is giving me an internal server error.

Comment: " it is giving me internal server error" - Please post the error log

Comment: Nov 30 12:10:22 kapil-kapoor dhclient[1734]: message repeated 6 times: [ DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.0.100 on wlp1s0 to 192.168.0.1 port 67 (xid=0x28504551)]
Nov 30 12:10:34 kapil-kapoor org.gnome.zeitgeist.SimpleIndexer[1673]: ** (zeitgeist-fts:2331): WARNING **: Unable to get info on application://nautilus-autostart.desktop
Nov 30 12:10:43 kapil-kapoor dhclient[1734]: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.0.100 on wlp1s0 to 192.168.0.1 port 67 (xid=0x28504551)

Comment: Now I have created virtual host so url is :       demo/xyz/app/index.php      but don't want to use app directory with in the url and don't want to show the file extension can you suggest anything for this ?

Comment: @KapilKapoor : add a redirection it's simplifies your work.

Comment: @kranthi No, redirect will not work here because if I am redirecting url it is giving error "requested url not found"... basically I have added htaccess file to xyz folder and want to point app folder through htaccess so there will be no need to add app directory name in the url   :(